# Can't use retweet twitter API from node.js - error code 34

Tags: node.js, api, twitter

I'm trying to figure out of a simple node.js script to retweet using Twitter API. I was able to create favorites, post status, but a retweet is not working.

```
// rt.js
var Twitter = require('twitter');
var config = require('./config.js');
var T = new Twitter(config);

T.post('statuses/retweet/:id', {
  id: '870436914322472960'
}, (err, data, response) => {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err)
  } else {
    console.log(`${data.text} retweet success!`)
  }
})
```

The error message is :

```
[ { message: 'Sorry, that page does not exist', code: 34 } ]
```

I'm using : twitter@1.7.0 (from npm list)

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Try removing single quotes around the id value

Comment: @Brian no, same error message.

Comment: I think I remember code 34 being invalid access tokens. Try regenerating your tokens, or check if the twitter class has been configured properly: https://www.npmjs.com/package/twitter

Comment: Its a : "Corresponds with HTTP 404 - the specified resource was not found."(https://dev.twitter.com/overview/api/response-codes) and with same access token, i can post, favorite, and search.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is working using :

```
T.post('statuses/retweet/' + '871703983521492993', (err, data, response) => {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err)
  } else {
    console.log(`${data.text} retweet success!`)
  }
})
```

OR

```
var id = '870659570703708160'
 T.post('statuses/retweet/' + id, (err, data, response) => {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err)
  } else {
    console.log(`${data.text} retweet success!`)
  }
})
```